# Laravel - how do i get the count data in query?

Tags: database, laravel

This is the query in mysql

> select e_id, h_name,
>   d_name,drf_name,credit_num,is_required,e_semester,stdate,endate,c_month,num
>   from(SELECT electcourse.id e_id,
>   h_id,d_id,ref_id,e_semester,stdate,endate,c_month,count(e_id) as num
>   FROM `electcourse` left join `period` on `p_id`= period.`id` left join
>   `hospitalxdepartment` on `hd_id`= hospitalxdepartment.`id` left join
>   `board` on electcourse.`id`= `e_id` where `st_id`= 'admin' group by
>   `e_id`) T left join `hospital` on `h_id` = hospital.`id` left join
>   `department` on `d_id` = department.`id` left join
>   `departmentreference` on `ref_id` = `drfid` where `df_semester`=105

This is my query in the laravel, but it got some error message.

```
public function get_course($st_id,$semester){
        $from=DB::table('electcourse')
                ->selectRaw('electcourse.id as e_id','h_id','d_id','ref_id','e_semester','stdate','endate','c_month','count(e_id) as num',)
                ->leftjoin('period','p_id','period.id')
                ->leftjoin('hospitalxdepartment','hd_id','hospitalxdepartment.id')
                ->leftjoin('board','electcourse.id','e_id')
                ->where('st_id','=',$st_id)
                ->where('e_semester','=',$semester)
                ->groupBy('e_id');
        $query=DB::query()
                ->select('e_id','h_name','d_name','drf_name','credit_num','is_required','e_semester','stdate','endate','c_month')
                ->fromSub($from, 'T')
                ->leftjoin('hospital','h_id','hospital.id')
                ->leftjoin('department','d_id','department.id')
                ->leftjoin('departmentreference','ref_id','drfid')
                ->where('df_semester','=',$semester)->orderBy('c_month')->get();
        return $query;

    }
```

I make sure it will be work if i didnt use count in the "select" string. 
Have anyone know how to fix it with the correct count method?

> error message : "Class App\Repositories\BoardRepository does not
>   exist"
>   This is mean DB format is wrong.

Comment: Can you please tell us what the error message said? It's likely important.

Comment: @ceejayoz sure. error message

Comment: The error message you've posted doesn't have anything to do with this query or this portion of code you've shared. Your problem is somewhere else. It should've given you a file and line number where your code is attempting to use a class named `BoardRepository`.

Comment: i think there has some error format in my laravel query.  This error message will be showed if i had some format error in the DB query. @ceejayoz

Comment: The error message you've shared with us has nothing to do with this query or code. Somewhere (again, the error message should tell you) you're trying to use a `BoardRepository` class, but Laravel is looking for a file in `app/Repositories/BoardRepository.php` with `class BoardRepository { ... }` in it, and is unable to find it.

Comment: but .... if i change my select to =>`->select('electcourse.id as e_id','h_id','d_id','ref_id','e_semester','stdate','endate','c_month')` , it will be work. Everything will be ok!! @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to generate a correct query, but it will get error message.

query function

```
public function get_course($st_id,$semester){

    $from=DB::table('electcourse')
            ->select('electcourse.id as e_id','h_id','d_id','ref_id','e_semester','stdate','endate','c_month',DB::raw('count(e_id) as num'))
            ->leftjoin('period','p_id','period.id')
            ->leftjoin('hospitalxdepartment','hd_id','hospitalxdepartment.id')
            ->leftjoin('board','electcourse.id','e_id')
            ->where('st_id','=',$st_id)
            ->where('e_semester','=',$semester)
            ->groupBy('e_id');
    $query=DB::query()
            ->select('e_id','h_name','d_name','drf_name','credit_num','is_required','e_semester','stdate','endate','c_month')
            ->fromSub($from, 'T')
            ->leftjoin('hospital','h_id','hospital.id')
            ->leftjoin('department','d_id','department.id')
            ->leftjoin('departmentreference','ref_id','drfid')
            ->where('df_semester','=',$semester)->orderBy('c_month')->get();
    return $query;

}
```

Error message :

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'yangming567.electcourse.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `e_id`,
>   `h_name`, `d_name`, `drf_name`, `credit_num`, `is_required`,
>   `e_semester`, `stdate`, `endate`, `c_month` from (select
>   `electcourse`.`id` as `e_id`, `h_id`, `d_id`, `ref_id`, `e_semester`,
>   `stdate`, `endate`, `c_month`, count(e_id) as num from `electcourse`
>   left join `period` on `p_id` = `period`.`id` left join
>   `hospitalxdepartment` on `hd_id` = `hospitalxdepartment`.`id` left
>   join `board` on `electcourse`.`id` = `e_id` where `st_id` = admin and
>   `e_semester` = 105 group by `e_id`) as `T` left join `hospital` on
>   `h_id` = `hospital`.`id` left join `department` on `d_id` =
>   `department`.`id` left join `departmentreference` on `ref_id` =
>   `drfid` where `df_semester` = 105 order by `c_month` asc)
>   However, i copy this error message query to Mysql, and it is work!!!!
>   Have anyone know how to fix my query in laravel?